# 12 points are given in a plane of which 5 and only 5 are aligned. How many triangles can be formed with vertices in 3 of the 12 points?

Tags: combinatorics

12 points are given in a plane of which 5 and only 5 are aligned. How many triangles can be formed with vertices in 3 of the 12 points?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Math Stack Exchange. Eu traduzi sua pergunta para o inglês. Por favor, poste futuras perguntas em inglês. Obrigado!

Comment: Please write in English. Other people may don't know Portuguese.

Comment: tudo bem, obrigado!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could define 3 state for drawing triangles. 5 Allende and 7 not.

1. All 3 points of triangels are in 7.
   $$\binom{7}{3}$$
2. One of 3 points is in 5 and 2 are in 7.
   $$\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{1}$$
3. Two of 3 points are  in 5 and 1 is in 7.
   $$\binom{7}{1}\binom{5}{2}$$

$$\binom{7}{3}+\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{1}+\binom{7}{1}\binom{5}{2}$$

Comment: This solution looks good, too,

Comment: @InterstellarProbe. Thanks. So please add some points to my account!

Answer (score 4):

Out of 12 points, choose three. Subtract cases when all three points are collinear (all three are chosen from the five collinear points).

$$\dbinom{12}{3}-\dbinom{5}{3} = 220-10 = 210$$

Comment: Bravo! Bravo! Bravo!